# How do I get Raspberry Pi Pico to mount to the same Linux device every time it's in BOOTSEL mode?

Tags: linux, pi-pico, pi-pico-w

Basically what's happening:

- I plug in my Pico W to my Raspberry Pi 4B (8GB model, running Ubuntu Server 23.10 arm64) via USB while holding down the button, so it's in BOOTSEL mode.
- I run `sudo dmesg` on the Pi 4B to see that there's a new mass storage device attached, i.e. the Pico's flash partition.
- I manually mount the drive with `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/pico`
- I copy a UF2 "hello world" binary onto the Pico, runs as expected
- I unplug the Pico and get back to work on programming.
- I plug the Pico back in to install a new binary on it.

The issue happens in the last step. When I run `sudo dmesg` again to see the name of the new mass storage device, it "shifts up" by one letter, like if it was `sdb` last time, the next time it'll be `sdc`. This seemingly goes on forever, but I haven't hit Z yet. Furthermore, the letters 'reset' when I reboot the Pi 4B, so it's back to `sdb` on the first time I plug the Pico in after a reboot. (I have a proper HDD attached on `sda`.)

How can I get my Pi 4B to reuse the same logical mass storage device for every time I plug my Pico back in BOOTSEL mode?

Comment: "How can I get my Pi 4B to reuse the same logical mass storage device for every time I plug my Pico back in BOOTSEL mode" reboot before plugging it in.

Answer (score 0):

Assignment of the device names (`sda`, `sdb`, etc) is a function of the Linux kernel. If that's not bad enough, since `systemd` [horned in](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/horned+in) on the action, what you're trying to do will involve following `systemd` guidance as well.

This is a completely **un-tested** idea:

1. cobble together a **script** that reads the latest device name of your Pico (you could use `lsblk` as a source for the device name)
2. add logic to the **script** that will create a [symbolic link](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-symbolic-links-in-linux-using-the-ln-command/) from whatever the latest device name is to something like **`pico`**; i.e.:

```
KERNEL=="<the currently-assigned device name from step 1>", SYMLINK+="pico"
```

3. Install the script in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` using a filename like `20-devsymlink.rules`.

This should be trivial for someone who's labeled himself as `HackerDaGreat`.

Comment: I'll try this out when I get time. Btw, I came up with the username when I was a silly 11-year-old; we've all been there!

Comment: I didn't try your solution exactly, but I used the first part about getting a new device's name as the base for my own script. See the [answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/145470/153808) I posted on this question.  

**P.S. I can't for the life of me figure out why I can't directly ping you. The ping thingy seems to be broken for me on this website.*

Comment: Oh - the *ping thing* is because you're posting under my thread/answer... that means I always get a notice. You OTOH are one of potentially several commenters, so I use your handle to ensure you get notification.       WRT your solution: Good For You! If it works, you should **accept** it as the answer (may have to wait a day or two??); that helps others, but you get no points for it :(

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't end up getting the whole "reuse the same device name" thing working, but I DID end up making a solution that fit my exact use case.

Basically what this script does, is it essentially gets the logical device name of the Pico through some semi-"hacky" means which involve a few assumptions[1] about your environment (I used Ubuntu Server 23.10). Then it mounts that device to a directory of your choice. After that, it copies a UF2 binary of your choice to the mount point, which triggers execution of the new binary on the Pico, which is what I was looking for.

[**deploy.sh**](https://github.com/ardent-nss/rppw-research/blob/main/deploy.sh)

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# deploy.sh: write a UF2 binary to a Raspberry Pi Pico (W) in BOOTSEL mode
# Probably needs root to work properly! (mount and cp commands)

mount_location=/mnt/pico # where the flash partition shall be mounted
                         # (no trailing slash, please)
binary=a0_bl.uf2 # the UF2 binary to send to the Pico

before=$(lsblk -o NAME) # get existing devices
read -n 1 -s -r -p "Plug the Pico in BOOTSEL mode. Press Enter when finished."
echo # runs when Enter is pressed
after=$(lsblk -o NAME) # get new device list

diff=$(diff <(printf "$before") <(printf "$after")) # find new/changed device
                                                    # (presumed to be the Pico)
dev_name=$(printf "$diff" | grep '^> └─' | cut -c 9-) # get name of the Pico

mount /dev/${dev_name} ${mount_location} # mount the Pico's flash partition
cp $binary ${mount_location} # copy over the UF2 binary

printf "\nDeployed.\n" # It works on my machine™, so no error handling
```

Thanks @Seamus for parts of the basic idea.

[1]: The only "assumptions" made about the environment are:

- Devices are accessible under the directory `/dev`;
- You have Bash installed to `/bin/bash`;
- The script is run with root permissions (primarily due to use of the `mount` command);
- And that `lsblk -o NAME` prepends `> └─` before partition names.

P.S. for anyone wondering, once you hit `sdz` in device names, the next device will be named `sdaa`.